# htaccess rewrite specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i try so many times to do this:
remove .php from all php pages in my website and it work and link become like this
localhost/settings
but, i want profile.php?username=id to become localhost/adam the username, but it didn't work
so i try to change index.php to another page also not working.
why i can't write two RewriteRule in same htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /dracsnape/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: _“why i can't write two RewriteRule in same htaccess”_ - you _can_ of course do that - but they also have to make _sense_, in combination. When you request `/adam` here, your RewriteConds and the following Rule will rewrite this to `adam.php` already - which probably does not exist. You need to be more specific in your conditions/patterns here - or in what URLs you want to specifically rewrite to begin with. […]

Comment: […] Between `localhost/adam`, and `localhost/logo.png`, there’s currently no distinction made in your attempt, and `^(.*)$` would match the latter as well - so you would rewrite that to `/dracsnape/profile.php?username=logo.png`, and that might not be what you want to begin with … Checking if what was requested physically exists as a file (or folder), and only rewrite if that is not the case, is a very common approach.

Comment: I understand that, then i want to make profile.php is main page insted index.php and remove .php from all pages, how i can do that ?

Comment: but in facebook i see that they do it, like www.facebook.com this index and www.facebook.com/zuck this for profile and so on